# How to set a limit on dynamically generated table rows?

Tags: javascript, html, css, thymeleaf

I have a dynamically generated tables, each time page is refresh a new row of data is inserted. How can I restrain the table where it will only show a maximum of 7 table rows, and once it reaches 7. Update the table existing table row with data instead of adding a new row. My application consist of thymeleaf for front end, java/springboot for back end.

I am using thyme leaf with this script to auto generate my code.

```
<table th:object="${showbudata}">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Date </th>
        <th> Status </th>
        <th> HostName </th>
        <th> Implement Version</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

  <tr th:each="t: ${showbudata}" th:if="${server.host == t.host}">
    <td th:text="${t.date}" />
    <td th:text="${t.Status}" />
    <td th:text="${t.host}" />
    <td th:text="${t.version}" />
  </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: that's gonna be js logic so you should include more of that, not html

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement as named `pagination` for your data. You might be interested to have a look at [Thymeleaf Spring Data Dialect](https://github.com/jpenren/thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect).

Comment: I looked at pagination, I don't think that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As your page is getting refresh and you wan't to keep a track of max row you can use localStorage as

```
var max = 5;
var currentRowsCount = localStorage.get('rowsInsreted') || 0;
if(currentRowsCount < max){
  // insert new row 
  localStorage.setItem("rowsInsreted", currentRowsCount+1));
}
```

[Nice article for localstorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)